# Convert string list to list in python

Tags: python, string, list

I have a string as below ,

```
val = '["10249/54","10249/147","10249/187","10249/252","10249/336"]'
```

I need to parse it and take the values after / and put into list as below

```
['54','147','187','252','336']
```

**My code**:  `[a[a.index('/')+1:] for a in val[1:-1].split(',')]`

**Output** : `['54"', '147"', '187"', '252"', '336"']`

It has double quotes also " which is wrong.
After i tried as below

```
c = []
for a in val[1:-1].split(','):
    tmp = a[1:-1]
    c.append(tmp[tmp.index('/')+1:])
```

**Output :**

```
['54', '147', '187', '252', '336']
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in one line using `literal_eval`:

```
from ast import literal_eval

val = ['54','147','187','252','336']
a = [i.split('/')[-1] for i in literal_eval(val)]

print(a)
```

Output:

```
['54', '147', '187', '252', '336']
```

`literal_eval()` converts your string into a list, and then `i.split('/')[-1]` grabs what's after the slash.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah ... assuming every value has a `/` like your example, this is superior:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>>
>>> val = '["10249/54","10249/147","10249/187","10249/252","10249/336"]'
>>> [int(i.split('/')[1]) for i in literal_eval(val)]
[54, 147, 187, 252, 336]
```

*edited to insert a forgotten bracket

Comment: he wants a list of strings: `[str(i.split('/')[1]) for i in literal_eval(val)]` swap `int` with `str`

Comment: I ... guess?  I think he wants ints, but he's trying to get strings so he can `map(int)`.  In any case, I prefer the answer written this way. Up to the OP to choose.

Comment: that's a little overanswering (integer conversion isn't needed), but yeah, probably what OP will ask next :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using regular expressions!

You can do it in a single line this way.

```
import re

val = '["10249/54","10249/147","10249/187","10249/252","10249/336"]'

output = re.findall('/(\d+)', val) # returns a list of all strings that match the pattern

print(output)
```

**Result:**
`['54', '147', '187', '252', '336']`

`re.findall` generates a new list called with all the matches of the regexp. Check out the [docs on regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html) for more info on this topic.

Comment: it works the same in python 2. Hint: it's better to put the result of the `print` in your answer so others can visually check that it works as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module to convert the string to list

```
>>> import json
>>> val ='["10249/54","10249/147","10249/187","10249/252","10249/336"]'
>>> list(map(lambda x: x.split('/')[-1], json.loads(val)))
>>> ['54', '147', '187', '252', '336']
```